# Error while parsing 2018-05-01T00:00:00 date using Instant.parse

Tags: java, datetime, java.time.instant

Here is my code which i am using to parse string using Instant.parse ,

```
String date = "2018-05-01T00:00:00";
Instant.parse(date)
```

And getting below error

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2018-05-01T00:00:00' could not be parsed at index 19
        at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
        at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
        at java.time.Instant.parse(Instant.java:395)
```

I cannot use other then **Instant** so looking solution for it only!

Comment: Which time zone is that local time supposed to be in? You can't parse to an instant without a time zone. If it's in UTC, you can simply add a "Z" to the end of the string before parsing.

Comment: I am not sure about that as i am getting it from third party api response!

Comment: You should check the documentation of the third party api.

Comment: `2018-05-01T00:00:00` does not define a moment in time, an instant. If you can find out what time zone or UTC offset was implied, we can help you convert to `Instant`. It seems the time of day doesn’t matter, though? So why not just parse into `LocalDate`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Instant.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) will only accept the string that are in [ISO INSTANT FORMAT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT)

> Obtains an instance of Instant from a text string such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30.00Z.
>
> The string must represent a valid instant in UTC and is parsed using `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`.

But the String you have represents [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). Like your input, a `LocalDateTime` represents only a date with time-of-day, but no offset nor time zone. So parse your input into `LocalDateTime`. You can then apply an offset or time zone to convert into [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

> A date-time without a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30.

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date);
Instant instant = dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).toInstant();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String date = "2018-05-01T00:00:00Z";
```

will do the trick (Note the 'Z' at the end). It will give you instant time for UTC.