# Why SimpleDateFormat setTimeZone doesn't throws error for invalid timezone

Tags: java, validation, timezone, datetime-parsing

I'm using SimpleDateFormat to convert string type of time to unix timestamp, but when I set timezone to an illegal value, I still got the correct result, is that how SimpleDateFormat.parse() method defined? If I wanna to have a unit test to test the failure case, how can I do that?

```
String str = "2016-06-21-10-19-22";

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("fewfefewf"));

Date date = df.parse(str);

long epoch = date.getTime();
System.out.println(epoch);
```

Comment: I recommend you neither use `SimpleDateFormat`, `TimeZone` nor `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime`, `DateTimeFormatter` and `ZoneId`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). The modern `ZoneId` will give you the validation that your asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of [getTimeZone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone-java.lang.String-) method that returns default `GMT` zone if the specified TimeZone cannot be understood

> the specified TimeZone, or the GMT zone if the given ID cannot be understood.

If would recommend to validate is by using [TimeZone.getAvailableIDs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getAvailableIDs--), and easy check to validate input timezone is valid or not

```
Arrays.stream(TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()).anyMatch(tz->tz.equals("fewfefewf"))
```

And the final recommendation please use the j[ava-8 date time api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes and start moving away from `SimpleDateFormat`

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"); // make sure you use H for hours in format

LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str,formatter);
```

Comment: Hi @Deadpool, based on this, Is there any other method to convert string type of time to unix timestamp that will fail when I have illegal timezone?

Comment: Just validated it before converting as i showed @zzxdw

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but seems I cant use DateTimeFormatter in my case, I tried time format like "2013-09-29T18:46:19Z", it will have an exception.

Comment: that's different format, just try googling with different formats https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61409243/error-while-parsing-2018-05-01t000000-date-using-instant-parse/61409497#61409497

Comment: thanks, I think I will still using SimpleDateFormat,  SimpleDateFormat is able to parse all the formats. If using DateTimeFormatter, need to convert localDateTime to localDate in some cases..such as "2016-06-21-10-19-22"

Comment: Of course you not only can use but will also benefit from using `DateTimeFormatter` and the other classes from java.time. The exception you are talking about, is that the one I am addressing in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61417933/5772882)?

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. Among its many advantages is that in many cases it gives you far better validation than the old classes like `TimeZone`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Here’s my shot at the modern equivalent of your code:

```
    String str = "2016-06-21-10-19-22";

    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss");

    ZonedDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, dtf)
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("fewfefewf"));

    long epoch = dateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    System.out.println(epoch);
```

Running it produces:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2016-06-21-10-19-22' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {MicroOfSecond=0, MinuteOfHour=19, NanoOfSecond=0, MilliOfSecond=0, SecondOfMinute=22, HourOfAmPm=10},ISO resolved to 2016-06-21 of type java.time.format.Parsed
>     at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:2017)
>     at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1952)
>     at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
>     at ovv.misc.MiscTest.<init>(MiscTest.java:72)
>     at ovv.misc.MiscTest.main(MiscTest.java:61)
> Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {MicroOfSecond=0, MinuteOfHour=19, NanoOfSecond=0, MilliOfSecond=0, SecondOfMinute=22, HourOfAmPm=10},ISO resolved to 2016-06-21 of type java.time.format.Parsed
>     at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.from(LocalDateTime.java:461)
>     at java.base/java.time.format.Parsed.query(Parsed.java:235)
>     at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
>     ... 3 more
> Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalTime from TemporalAccessor: {MicroOfSecond=0, MinuteOfHour=19, NanoOfSecond=0, MilliOfSecond=0, SecondOfMinute=22, HourOfAmPm=10},ISO resolved to 2016-06-21 of type java.time.format.Parsed
>     at java.base/java.time.LocalTime.from(LocalTime.java:431)
>     at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.from(LocalDateTime.java:457)
>     ... 5 more
> ```

Surprised? java.time has already found a bug that you didn’t ask about: in the format pattern string you need uppercase `HH` for hour of day from 00 through 23. Lowercase `hh` is for clock hour of AM or PM from 01 through 12. The detail to note in the error message is `HourOfAmPm=10` — this is not what you intended. Let’s fix and run again:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");
```

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.time.zone.ZoneRulesException: Unknown time-zone ID: fewfefewf
>     at java.base/java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider.getProvider(ZoneRulesProvider.java:279)
>     at java.base/java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider.getRules(ZoneRulesProvider.java:234)
>     at java.base/java.time.ZoneRegion.ofId(ZoneRegion.java:120)
>     at java.base/java.time.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:408)
>     at java.base/java.time.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:356)
>     at ovv.misc.MiscTest.<init>(MiscTest.java:73)
>     at ovv.misc.MiscTest.main(MiscTest.java:61)
> ```

I believe that this is what you asked for. If we fix this error too, the code runs flawlessly:

```
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, dtf)
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Eirunepe"));
```

> 1466522362000

I put in a random time zone, but I think that you know which one you want.

The other answers have already explained nicely what went wrong in your code. I know of no way to persuade the old and poorly designed `TimeZone` class to validate the time zone ID string.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: Hi Ole V.V., when I set date to "2016-06-21", and DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"), I got ```Text '2016-06-21' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2016-06-21 of type java.time.format.Parsed```, this error..

Comment: Yes you do, @zzxdw. [Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor when parsing LocalDateTime (Java 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454025/unable-to-obtain-localdatetime-from-temporalaccessor-when-parsing-localdatetime). Always good to paste your error message into your search engine. Your string contains a date and no time so cannot be parsed into a date *and* time,  which is what a `LocalDateTime` is. Try for example `LocalDate.parse("2016-06-21").atTime(LocalTime.of(13, 37))` or `LocalDate.parse("2016-06-21").atStartOfDay()`.

Comment: what if I have these two formats(date with time, date with no time) at the same time, how to make those into one function?